# meaning of print results of qr in perl

Tags: regex, perl

From [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), I see

```
$rex = qr/my.STRING/is;
print $rex; # prints (?si-xm:my.STRING)
```

But I am not sure how to understand `(?si-xm:...)`. If I do a print on `qr/quick|lazy/`, I got `(?-xism:quick|lazy)`. What does it mean here `(?-xism:...)` too?

Thanks!

Comment: Based on my guess, it seems to be a list of the flags you specified, a hyphen, and then a list of the flags you didn't specify. Not sure why it wouldn't include `p` or `o` in that list, though...

Comment: @Chris Lutz: `/p` and `/o` can't apply to a parenthesized sub-part of a regular expression. The main reason that regexes have an overloaded stringification operator is so that you can interpolate them into larger regexes. (They get stringified, then interpolated, and the larger regex gets re-parsed.) It is neither possible nor meaningful for `/p` and `/o` to be preserved during that.

Comment: @ruakh - Ah. That makes a lot of sense, then. I thought it was just for debugging purposes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think debugging purposes are part of it; if you print `qr/.../p`, then you will see `(?p-xism:...)`; the `p` flag has no actual effect when reinterpolated into a new regex, but it does affect the existing regex, so I guess it was considered informative to include it in the stringification. (`$foo = qr/x/p; $bar =~ m/$foo/` is equivalent to `$bar =~ m/x/p`, because despite how it may look, it doesn't actually stringify and re-interpolate.) The same is not done with `/o`, however, presumably because it's not actually in the regex object.

Comment: Some flags apply to the operator, and some to the pattern. For that reason, the operator flags are not part of the pattern and you won't see them in the stringification.

Comment: @ruakh, There's a whole lot more weirdness than that regarding `(?p:)`. I just filed a [ticket](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=101938) regarding this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As explained in the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) man-page:

> Any letters between `?` and `:` act as flags modifiers [...]

The letters before the `-` are positive modifiers; those after it are negative modifiers. So, for example, `(?-xism:quick|lazy)` means that whitespace and comments are *not* allowed inside the parentheses, the parenthesized part is *not* case-sensitive, a dot `.` does *not* match newlines, and `^` and `$` do *not* match line-start and line-end.

Answer (score 11):

Just as a note, the `(?FLAGS:pattern)` syntax has gotten a change with perl 5.14.0, and regex strinigification has changed along with it. To quote from `perlre`:

> Starting in Perl 5.14, a "^" (caret or circumflex accent) immediately after the "?" is a shorthand equivalent to "d-imsx".  Flags (except "d") may follow the caret to override it.  But a minus sign is not legal with it.

(`d` is one of a group of new flags in 5.14 that affects how regexes are affected by Unicode; `d`, the default, means to act basically like older Perl versions).

With the addition of the `(?^FLAGS:pattern)` syntax, regex stringification changes to use this syntax, and only list the flags that differ from the default. So `qr/hello/` stringifies as `(?^:hello)` (formerly `(?-xism:hello)`) and `qr/hello/i` stringifies as `(?^i:hello)` (formerly `(?i-xsm:hello)`).

The advantage of this change is that if perl 5.16 were to add a new `q` regex modifier (for "run this match on a quantum computer"), `qr/hello/` won't have to change to stringify to `(?d-xismq:hello)` — it will be able to stay `(?^:hello)` as it is on 5.14.

Answer (score 0):

They represent `/x`, `/i`, `/s`, `/m` if the letter appears on the left of the `-`, and the lack of the modifier if the letter appears on the right of the `-`.

The purpose of the code is used to transmit which flags were specified

```
>perl -E"$re = qr/./s;  say qq{a\nb} =~ /a${re}b/ ? 'match' : 'no match'"
match

>perl -E"$pat = '.';  say qq{a\nb} =~ /a${pat}b/ ? 'match' : 'no match'"
no match

>perl -E"$pat = '(?s-xim:.)';  say qq{a\nb} =~ /a${pat}b/ ? 'match' : 'no match'"
match
```

...and which weren't.

```
>perl -E"$re = qr/./;  say qq{a\nb} =~ /a${re}b/s ? 'match' : 'no match'"
no match

>perl -E"$pat = '.';  say qq{a\nb} =~ /a${pat}b/s ? 'match' : 'no match'"
match

>perl -E"$pat = '(?-xism:.)';  say qq{a\nb} =~ /a${pat}b/s ? 'match' : 'no match'"
no match
```

`(?:...)` is documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).